# how to pass an id to servlet withour using get?

Tags: html, jsp

how to pass an id without using get method? only the post method..

here is my code having a get method:

```
<c:forEach var="student" items="${studentList}">
    <tr>
    <td><c:out value="${student.firstName}" /></td>
    <td><c:out value="${student.middleName}" /></td>
    <td><c:out value="${student.lastName}" /></td>
    <td><c:out value="${student.yearLevel}" /></td>
    <td><c:out value="${student.scholarship}" /></td>
    <td><a href="student?page=edit&id=${student.id}">Edit</a></td>
    <td><a href="student?page=delete&id=${student.id}">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

i tried to use

```
   <input type="hidden" name="edit" value="${student.id}">
   <input type="hidden" name="delete" value="${student.id}">
```

but the first student in list will always be edited and the first in the list of students will be deleted

Comment: It isn't clear if `student?page=delete` actually asks for confirmation in the target page or not, but if it doesn't, then you've another major problem when a searchbot comes along crawling the links. You should definitely make non-idempotent requests such as create/update/delete a POST request using `<form method="post">`

Comment: i tried the method post for input type hidden but the problem is only the first in the list of students will be deleted or edited if click edit.

Comment: @BalusC: i tried <input type="hidden" name="id" value="${student.id}"> but the only id can be fetch will be the first on the list....

Comment: I wasn't answering your question, just merely pointing out a major design problem :) Your question was at that moment already answered by Slaks for  long, so I didn't post one.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a separate `<form>` tag for each button.

Otherwise, all of your buttons will share all of the inputs in the form.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to use jQuery, you could do something like that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $(".studentAction").off("click").on("click", function() {
        var url = "student";
        url += "?page=" + $(this).attr("name");
        url += "&id=" + $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            async: false,
            success: function(data) {
                // on success
            },
            error: function(data) {
                // on error
            }
        };
    });
});
</script>

<input class="studentAction" type="hidden" name="edit" value="${student.id}">
<input class="studentAction" type="hidden" name="delete" value="${student.id}">
```

Comment: how do i get the value in servlet from that javascript?